# Bean Validation de campos dependentes

Tags: java

Estou iniciando com bean validation e estou necessitando fazer validação de campos dependentes.

Exemplo : Tenho os campos dataInicio e dataFim 
O campo dataFim não pode ser menor que o dataInicio.

Sei que posso criar minha própria anotação, mas não sei como ou se é possível utilizar o campo dataInicio no validador do dataFim.

---

Consegui criar o validador pelo exemplo da 
[questão/9284450](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284450/jsr-303-validation-if-one-field-equals-something-then-these-other-fields-sho%20c)

Comment: Da última vez que eu verifiquei a API, não dava para fazer isto nativamente. Porém você poderia criar um validador para a classe como um todo e então compara os campos. A desvantagem é que fica difícil reaproveitar o código e na época tinha que fazer uso de métodos específicos da implementação que eu estava usando.

Comment: Tens alguma documentação de como criar o validador para classe ?

Comment: Consegui um exemplo no link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121847/bean-validation-de-campos-dependentes